# Activity with only search view is taking two taps of back button to go to previous activity when android:iconifiedByDefault attribute is set to false

Tags: android

1.This is the activity I'm calling

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/activity_contacts"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_margin="0dp"
   android:padding="0dp"
   tools:context="com.example.hangout1.contacts">

      <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:padding="0dp"
         android:layout_margin="0dp">

            <SearchView
               android:id="@+id/searchView"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="60dp"
               android:queryHint="Enter a name or number"
               android:iconifiedByDefault="true"
               android:inputType="text"
               />
      </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

2.This is how I'm calling it

```
 public void loadContacts(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(GroupMembersActivity.this,contacts.class);
    startActivity(intent);
 }
```

I'm new to android. When attribute 'iconifiedByDefault' is set to 'true' and if I'm not touching the search icon(not expanding), touching the back button once takes me back to the previous activity(the one called this activity). But if it is set to 'false' it takes two touches on back button to go back to the previous activity. Please let me know a little insights on this behavior. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The searchview is by default set to focusable=true, which means the query area in the search view was active, like ready for text to be entered. so it took one touch to exit from the focus and one for the activity to go back. when I set the attribute focusable to false, query area is not ready now and is ready only when touched. so one tap less. Here's what I did

```
android:focusable="false"
```